# How to test for reflexivity in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am currently working on a project in Python that **compares ordered pairs to a list** and **tests for reflexivity**.

I'm not sure I understand why it works. Can someone help explain what `a1` and `a2` are doing, and how they work in the for loop?

Here is the snippet:

```
    a = []
    y = []

    for a1, a2 in r:
        if (a1 == a2):
            y.append(a1)

        if (a1 not in a):
            a.append(a1)

    if (set(a) == set(y)):
        print("Reflexive: Yes")

    else:   
        print("Reflexive: No")
```

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your code adds a value in `y` when your pair is twice this value. So `y` will be the list of values in relation with themselves.
Besides, you add a value in `a` if it's not already in it. So `a` is (supposed to be)[1] the list of all values in the relation `r`.
Finally you decide your relation is reflexive if all values (list `a`) are in relation with themselves (list `y`).

[1] There seems to be a small mistake in that if a value is only present in the right (`a2`), you won't put it in `a` as you do when it's in the left (`a1`). Therefore the relation `r=[(1, 1), (1, 2)]` will be judged reflexive in your case.
To correct that, you could add:

```
    if a2 not in a:
        a.append(a2)
```

As the final test converts your lists `y` and `a` to sets, you could probably dispense with the test before inserting in `a`. You could also use sets from the onset instead of creating lists then converting them to sets.

Answer (score 0):

a1 and a2 are your ordered pairs. The first if statement compares them and if they are equal adds a1 to a vector y. Afterwards a1 gets added to vector a unless it is already a part of vector a. The last if Statement compares if vector a and y are equal.

This is a good test for reflexivity because the first statement checks wether any elements do not refer to themselves by not adding them to vector y and the second one checks for duplicates by not adding them to vector a. If both sets are equal in the end, they are reflexive.

Edit: Francis Colas is right about that mistake. Add his part to the code and you are good.